# Subscribe to google and outlook calendar through url causing problems

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, icalendar

I'm working on a project using Django Rest Framework and icalendar. I've created an api which provides ics file for download.
Users are provided with a url to the download api which they use to subscribe. However they are experiencing unexpected behaviour upon subscription.
In case of google calendar it doesn't resync automatically at all. In one instance the calendar was subscribed successfully but there were no events being displayed on google calendar.

Can anyone help confirm whether there is an issue with google calendar or am I missing something. for example not generating the file correctly

views.py

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], permission_classes=[AllowAny], authentication_classes=[])
def download_file(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    ics_data = instance.ics_data
    file_name = "somefile"
    response = HttpResponse(ics_data.encode(), content_type='text/calendar')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.ics' % file_name
    return response
```

sample url:
https://api-mycompany.com/users/11184/calendar/download_file/

sample ics data:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//my company calendar//
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:This Event
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220321T054500Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220321T070000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220419T085236Z
UID:113874
DESCRIPTION:Some Event
LOCATION:My Studio
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```